# YUM not installing certain packages from EPEL on CentOS 6

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, repository, yum

I've been trying to solve this problem all day, but with no such luck. I'm trying to install phpmyadmin and other packages from the EPEL repo, but the command (yum install phpmyadmin) returns with "No package phpmyadmin available".  I've installed and uninstalled EPEL countless times, but that hasn't helped either. Any help is GREATLY greatly appreciated.

$ yum repolist

```
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: centos.someimage.com
  * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
  * extras: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
  * remi: rpms.famillecollet.com
  * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
  * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
  * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
 repo id        repo name                                               status
 base           CentOS-6 - Base                                          6,281+86
 epel           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64          9,660+814
 extras         CentOS-6 - Extras                                              14
 remi           Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64        177+1,241
 rpmforge       RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                              4,559+91
 updates        CentOS-6 - Updates                                         457+61
 webtatic       Webtatic Repository EL6 - x86_64                           14+148
 repolist: 21,162
```

$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

```
 [epel]
 name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
 #baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
 mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&amp;arch=$basearch
 failovermethod=priority
 enabled=1
 gpgcheck=1
 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

 [epel-debuginfo]
 name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
 #baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
 mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-    6&amp;arch=$basearch
 failovermethod=priority
 enabled=0
 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
 gpgcheck=1

 [epel-source]
 name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
 #baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
 mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&amp;arch=$basearch
 failovermethod=priority
 enabled=0
 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
 gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: what does `yum list  phpMyAdmin*` ouput?

Comment: $ yum list phpMyAdmin*

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.someimage.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 * remi: remi.mirrors.hostinginnederland.nl
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Error: No matching Packages to list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jhughes@jhughes ~]$ sudo yum list phpMyAdmin
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: 192.168.0.10
 * elrepo-kernel: mirror.symnds.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: 192.168.0.10
 * updates: 192.168.0.10
Available Packages
phpMyAdmin.noarch                                        3.5.8.2-1.el6                                        epel

==============

This means that phpMyAdmin **is** in EPEL for EL6.

Do you have an **exclude=** line in your /etc/yum.conf file?

Do a **yum clean all** command and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yum clean all didn't help, but there was indeed an exclude line in the conf. I commented it out, and now it's working like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to do this...it did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently yum is case sensitive. That's said, try with:

`# yum install phpMyAdmin`

Comment: I already tried that as well, and it returns the same error: "No package phpMyAdmin available.".

Answer (score 0):

You need to have epel enabled and epel-source.